# How to merge the emitted values of multiple Observables into a single Observable emission?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that receives a DTO object and transforms it into an observable that emits the single transformed Entity. It has the following header:

`dtoTransformer(dto: DTO): Observable<Entity>`

I also have a function that returns an Observable emitting a list of DTOs:

`getDTOs(): Observable<DTO[]>`

Using these two I need to write a function that returns an observable of the `Entity` list, transformed from the DTOs received:

`getEntyties():Observable<Entity[]>`

My problem is applying the `dtoTransformer` to the values of the DTO list inside the observable. Is there an operator that can help me? I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `forkJoin` and `concatMap`. This is under the assumption that these are simple `httpClient` (completing) calls:

```
getEntities(): Observable<Entity[]> {
  return this.getDtos().pipe(
    concatMap((dtos) => forkJoin(
      dtos.map((dto) => this.dtoTransformer(dto))
    )
  )
}
```

What happens here:

1. Call http to get the `DTO[]`
2. Map this response to an array of http calls which by using `map`
3. Pass this array of observables to `forkJoin` which will do parallel calls and returns when all are completed (and not errored)

Obviously there are things that you need to take into account, when one http call errors, it doesn't return anything, so you need to add some fallback. If the `DTO[]` array is very big, you can hit a request limit, so perhaps some throttling can be put in place, or chunking by making a fixed amount in parallel and when those are done continue with the next batch